# MPMediaQuery.songsQuery().items returns nil

Tags: mpmediaquery

first time I am touching Mediaquery and I am stucked.
I have the following lines in xcode
import MediaPlayer
class ViewController: UIViewController{

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
         let mediaItems = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery().items
```

But media items is always empty / nil.

Any idea what I missed?
Ok I found the reason, this is very time consuming to find such information.

Simulator:
Unsupported frameworks include:

External Accessory
Media Player

Rpw

Answer (score 1):

Have you imported the MediaPlayer framework?

try this

```
import MediaPlayer
class CLASSNAME {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let allTracks: NSArray = MPMediaQuery.songsQuery().items as NSArray
        println("All tracks: \(allTracks)")
    }
}
```